# Real time examples of Spring Bean inheritence and its annotation version

Tags: java, spring

I am going through [Bean Definition Inheritence](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions), which is useful to re-use a bean definition in our spring configuration file.

How this concept is useful for a real time application, for example if I have a Amazon application what kind of scenario I can take where this is useful, can you please give me an example for understanding.

Also is there any equivalent functionality available using annotation approach, I have not seen any such option in the Spring document.